# NHibernate: Modifying different fields of an entity from two sessions

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity with multiple fields. There are two types of actions that may be performed on it: a long one, usually initiated by the user, and a short one, which is periodically run by the system. Both of these update the entity, but they touch different fields.

There can't be two concurrent long operations or two concurrent short operations. But the system may schedule a short operation while a long operation is in progress, and the two should execute concurrently. Since they touch different fields, I believe this should be possible.

I think NHibernate's change tracking should do the trick here - i.e., if one session loads an entity and updates some fields, and another session loads the same entity and updates different fields, then the two will not collide. However, I feel I shouldn't be relying on this because it sounds like an "optimization" or an "implementation detail". I tend to think of change tracking as an optimization to reduce database traffic, I don't want the functionality of the system to depend on it. Also, if I ever decide to implement optimistic concurrency for this entity, then I risk getting a StaleObjectException, even though I can guarantee that there is no actual collision.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Should I split the entity into two? Can't this affect database consistency (e.g. what if only one "half" of the entity is in the DB)? Can I use NHibernate to explicitly set only a single field of an entity? Am I wrong in not wanting to rely on change tracking to achieve functionality?

If it matters, I'm using Fluent NHibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the entity using `dynamic update`.

- `dynamic-update` (optional, defaults to false): Specifies that UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only those columns whose values have changed.

If you enable dynamic-update, you will have a choice of optimistic locking strategies:

- `version` check the version/timestamp columns
- `all` check all columns
- `dirty` check the changed columns
- `none` do not use optimistic locking

More information [here](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Doesn't this still rely on the change tracking "optimization", though? My concern is that I always thought of change tracking as a way of reducing DB queries for the purposes of optimization. I get this uncomfortable feeling relying on it for functional requirements (i.e. allowing two operations to run concurrently). Wouldn't it be more explicit (thus less prone to break due to accidental changes) to separate the data these two operations work on?

Comment: @telewin I still can't see the advantage of separating the entity. Dynamic update would only update the changed properties regardless of what's changed in it, and given that according to your model, both operations don't overlap the other's work, I still don't see the problem. :)

Comment: My concern is that people (i.e., other developers) might see change tracking as an optimization, which means that it can be turned off without affecting functionality. Wouldn't it surprise you if you changed the locking strategy from "dirty" to "version" and things stopped working? Separating the entity would prevent that from happening. Or are you arguing that the locking strategy should be considered part of the functionality, and so this is acceptable? Certainly, the choice between optimistic and pessimistic locking is part of the functionality (affects exceptions etc.).

Comment: @telewin I do think the locking strategy should. However, the main developer for NHibernate states that "We very strongly recommend that you use version/timestamp columns for optimistic locking with NHibernate. This is the optimal strategy with respect to performance and is the only strategy that correctly handles modifications made outside of the session (ie. when ISession.Update() is used). Keep in mind that a version or timestamp property should never be null, no matter what unsaved-value strategy, or an instance will be detected as transient."  http://goo.gl/6k9TU

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - neither version nor timestamp will work for my case. Are you saying that _dirty_ should not be used?